# Browser with multiple cookie storage

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

Which browser will let me login say to website if I open number of different instances, with different login credentials(hence storing cookie to instance cache instead of global browser cache).

Comment: If there is none, that would be a great new feature.

Comment: Duplicates ["Is there a browser that different instances doesn't use the same cookie for the same site?"](http://superuser.com/questions/198200/) and ["Different cookie storages in one browsers"](http://superuser.com/questions/216104/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly what you want, but I use Chrome incognito mode for this. I can open my gmail and my wife's gmail in the same Chrome instance.

You could also run Firefox with different profiles indicated on the command line. The cookies would be stored in the individual profile folders.

Comment: 1. Crome incognito is sharing cookie storage with other incognito sessions. 2. For using firefox I also have to copy the rest of profile data such as addons, settings, which is not so practical.